# Django: import auth user to the model

Tags: django, django-models

In Django I created a new model:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import user

class Workers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
        work_group = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        card_num = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.user
```

But it doesn't work: `ImportError: cannot import name user`

How to fix it?

I want to create a new table "workers" in db, which has a `OneToOne` relationship with table "auth_user".

Answer (score 227, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

You missed the models - and user is capitalized.

If you use a custom user model you should use:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

More details can be found in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

> **Changed in Django 1.11:**
>
> The ability to call get_user_model() at import time was added.

Comment: thanks a lot but on the django's doc it say no where models https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/
BTW Thanks again.

Answer (score 84):

If you're using a custom User model, do the following to reference it:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()
```

Or if using it in foreign key or many-to-many relations:

```
from django.conf import settings
....
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)

Comment: This is more correct than the accepted answer as it's more portable.

Answer (score 5):

`AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a good solution. here is the complete solution as per the question.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Workers(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    work_group = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    card_num = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.id
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to keep your code generic, use the `get_user_model()` method to retrieve the user model and the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting to refer to it when defining model's relations to the user model, instead of referring to the auth user model directly.

ref: [Django By Example](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/django-example) Book