# How to get user details in serializer in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I am trying to get users details from django using rest framework. but there is error:

> module 'core.model' has no attribute 'Users'

to do that I added this line in settings.py:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {     'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER':'users.serializers.userSerializer' }
```

Since it is a model of Django auth and in my models.py there is no model of such users it is from Django auth model and I don't know how to access the data from it.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from core import models

class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    fields=(
        'id',
        'username')
    model=models.Users
```

Here is the screenshot of my django admin:

[image: you can see clearly Users table from djnago auth]

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12921810/11697139

Comment: @CodingBee console shows plural name of models

Answer (score 0):

We must import `User` model like:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a custom User model inside the core app.

Be sure you have [substituted your User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) inside settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

Would be 'core.User' in your case, I believe.

Then to [reference your custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model) you can possibly:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.conf import settings
from core import models

class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    fields=(
        'id',
        'username')
    model=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

or

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from core import models

class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    fields=(
        'id',
        'username')
    model=get_user_model()
```